# PDO vs MySQLi. What do you think? PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I have been reading through a few articles on PDO and they seem to say switch over, MySQLi is outdated, etc.

It does look good, you can use lots of different types of SQL servers and still use the same functions. Better OO emphasis.

Below are a couple of the articles I read.

[Your MySQL Code Sucks.](http://webdevrefinery.com/forums/topic/1272-your-mysql-code-sucks)

[Why you Should be using PHP’s PDO for Database Access](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/)

What is the general consensus on here?

Comment: This question is really not a good fit for the SO Q&A format.  Generally questions should have a specific answer.  This one doesn't.  [Please read the FAQ](http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: @CharlesSprayberry Is there a better place to put it?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons

Comment: No reason not to use PDO

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysqli or PDO - what are the pros and cons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think there is a remote possibility you will need to use a different DB backend, then use PDO. If you know you will only be using MySQL and already know how to use it, or have a good library to wrap the `mysqli_*()` class of functions, just use that.